# Unwind segues---Animation

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I read a great explain about unwind segues from here:
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)
Then tried in my own project, everything works fine, only one question, as the "push segue" Xcode provides, the unwind segues perform with animation by default, I have to use a custom push segue to get rid of the animation followed by this:[Push segue in xcode with no animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209113/push-segue-in-xcode-with-no-animation)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PushNoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

---

```
#import "PushNoAnimationSegue.h"

@implementation PushNoAnimationSegue
-(void) perform{
    [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
@end
```

what can I do to turn off the animation of unwind segues as well. Can anyone help?

Comment: Apple has implemented unwind into sample project, take a look https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/UnwindSegue/Listings/CustomUnwindSegue_QuizContainerFadeViewControllerSegue_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013644-CustomUnwindSegue_QuizContainerFadeViewControllerSegue_m-DontLinkElementID_6 and you can set animation to no

Answer (score 3):

For iOS9:

Interface Builder (in Xcode 7) lists unwind segues. From there, you can select it and simply uncheck the `animated` property to turn off the unwind animation.

[image: Animates property of an unwind segue]

For iOS 7 and 8:

In the `unwind` method of the destination controller you have to pop with `animated: NO`.