# Is it possible for current visible view controller to break out of existing view hierarchy and be substituted to another?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

This is the question about non-trivial transition from one controller to another.

I have a team list screen which has Plus button (+) that when clicked modally opens navigation controller with root screen `Create Team Stage 1` after which `Create Team Stage 2` follows.

```
Team List -(modal presentation)-> NavigationController -(push)-> CreateTeam1 -(push)-> CreateTeam2
```

Also it is possible to fall into `Team N Details` screen after clicking on Team N from that Team List:

```
TeamList -(push)-> Team N
```

I have requirement that after new `team N` is created on `CreateTeam2` there should be `Team N Details` screen that appear modally so it could look the same as if we would fall into that Team N from the Team List screen (of course with navigation bar and < button in it).

The goal is to create presentation: `Create2 -(???)-> Team N` so that this newly created `Team N Details` screen was moved to another hierarchy so like it was presented as old existing team from Team List.

**Is it possible to archieve that kind of transition?**

P.S. I have already accomplished transition: `Create Team 2 -(dismiss/pop)-> Team List` using dismiss/pop, but it looks like we go to the `Team N Details` screen through blinking `Team List` and that looks bad in terms of user experience.

Comment: Can you upload a project? I'm sure it can be done thus I get a little bit lost with the explanation.

Comment: @Plasher, thank for response. I was able to solve my problem, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve that kind of transition:

Given I have custom segue: [Push segue in xcode with no animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209113/push-segue-in-xcode-with-no-animation) I do the following sequence of steps:

- On my `CreateTeam2` the team is created
- I do push with no animation: `TeamList -(push-no-animation)-> TeamN` (This does not affect current `CreateTeam2` screen that is currently on screen but as result I have `Team N` to be the top in that view hierarchy.
- Within `CreateTeam2` I do `[CreateTeam1 dismissOrPopViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

So it looks like `CreateTeam2` disappears and reveals already existing `Team N` screen - exactly what I needed.