# How do I perform a show detail segue without animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I need a way to transition to a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller from another view controller which is embedded in a different navigation controller **without the second view becoming embedded in the first controller.** I usually do this with a show detail segue however I need a way to do it without animation. I have tried creating a custom segue however I cannot find a way to set animation to false with a show detail segue.

Here is my attempt at making a custom segue. As you can see, there is no animation argument.

```
import UIKit


class PushNoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        if let source = sourceViewController as? UIViewController, dest = destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
            source.navigationController?.showDetailViewController(dest, sender: nil)
        }
    }


}
```

I cannot use a push segue [as specified in this proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209113/push-segue-in-xcode-with-no-animation) as I am moving to a different navigation controller containing a set of views and I don't want the views to become embedded in the original navigation controller as it messes with the navigation of the app.

Comment: Try to use pushViewController with animation param set to false, instead of showDetailViewController.
Sorry but I don't know Swift syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209113/push-segue-in-xcode-with-no-animation